# Execute bash-command with "at" (<<<) via python: syntax error, last token seen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, at-job

I'm using a radio sender on my RPi to control some light-devices at home. I'm trying to implement a time control and had successfully used the program "at" in the past.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess as sp
##### some code #####
sp.call(['at', varTime, '<<<', '\"sudo', './codesend', '111111\"'])
```

When I execute the program, i receive the

**errmsg**:
*syntax error. Last token seen: <*

*Garbled time*

This codesnipped works fine with every command by itself (as long every parameter is from type string).

It's neccessary to call "at" in this way: `at 18:25 <<< "sudo ./codesend 111111"` to hold the command in the queue (viewable in "atq"),
 because `sudo ./codesend 111111 | at 18:25` just executes the command directly and writes down the execution in "/var/mail/*user*".

My question ist, how can I avoid the syntax error.
**I'm using a lot of other packages in this program, so I have to stay with Python**

I hope someone has a solution for this problem or can help to find my mistake.
Many thanks in advance

Comment: `<<<` is not an argument to `at`. It's shell syntax. It has no meaning unless you embed it inside a shell script.

Comment: BTW, by default, `sudo` won't work in scenarios (like this one) where it isn't directly called at a TTY.

Comment: BTW, you could also have run `echo 'sudo ./codesend 111111' | at 18:25`; the `<<<` isn't so strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Preface: Shared Code

Consider the following context to be part of both branches of this answer.

```
import subprocess as sp
try:
    from shlex import quote # Python 3
except ImportError:
    from pipes import quote # Python 2

# given the command you want to schedule, as an array...
cmd = ['sudo', './codesend', '111111']

# ...generate a safely shell-escaped string.
cmd_str = ' '.join(quote(x) for x in cmd))
```

---

#### Solution A: Feed Stdin In Python

`<<<` is shell syntax. It has no meaning to `at`, and it's completely normal and expected for `at` to reject it if given as a literal argument.

You don't need to invoke a shell, though -- you can do the same thing directly from native Python:

```
p = sp.Popen(['at', vartime], stdin=sp.PIPE)
p.communicate(cmd_str)
```

---

#### Solution B: Explicitly Invoke A Shell

Moreover, `<<<` isn't `/bin/sh` syntax -- it's an extension honored in bash, ksh, and others; so you can't reliably get it just by adding the `shell=True` flag (which uses `/bin/sh` and so guarantees only POSIX-baseline features). If you want it, you need to explicitly invoke a shell with the feature, like so:

```
bash_script = '''
at "$1" <<<"$2"
'''
sp.call(['bash', '-c', bash_script,
         '_',                      # this is $0 for that script
         vartime,                  # this is its $1
         cmd_str,                  # this is its $2
         ])
```

---

In either case, note that we're using `shlex.quote()` or `pipes.quote()` (as appropriate for our Python release) when generating a shell command from an argument list; this is critical to avoid creating shell injection vulnerabilities in our software.

Comment: your solution with `sp.Popen()` is working. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Glad to help! If you no longer need additional answers, consider clicking the checkbox at the top of this one to accept it and mark your question solved.

Comment: A few things: first, you're trying to write a string to the subprocess's stdin, but it needs a bytestring. Second, it'd be simpler to pass the input to `communicate` instead of working with `p.stdin` manually, as well as safer when the input is large (avoiding cases where the pipe buffers get full and the processes deadlock).

Comment: @user2357112, good call on passing stdin to `communicate()` -- and I'll admit to doing most of my work in Python 2, so I completely missed the bytestring distinction.